# Congruence of nth degree

Tags: number-theory

Let $p$ - prime and $n>1$ - divisor of $p-1$ and $(A,p)=1$. Prove that if $A^{\frac{p-1}{n}}\equiv 1 \pmod p$ then congruence $x^n\equiv A \pmod p$ is solvable.

Please help

Comment: Please help by explaining your own thoughts first.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruence_theorem

Comment: I have any idea how to solve this. I am thinking about this problem more than two days but any result. May be it can be solved without discrete logarithm?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a generator $g\mod p$ of $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\ast}$. Now $A\equiv g^k\pmod p$. The given condition implies $$g^{\frac{p-1}{n}k}\equiv A^{\frac{p-1}{n}}\equiv 1\pmod p$$
Then $p-1\mid \frac{(p-1)k}{n}\implies n\mid k$. Hence $A\equiv r^n\pmod p$ which was to be proved.

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Thanks, I hope this is the one you were looking for.

Comment: Can I ask another question relating to this problem. How to prove that the remainder dividing $x^p-x$ into $x^n-A$ is equal to $(A^{\frac{p-1}{n}}-1)x$?

Comment: Well, I assume you are considering division $\mod p$, and for a new question you should make a new topic.