# $x^{(p-1)/d}$ takes d distinct values

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Im working on this [Exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcoTg.png)

I can do do part b) but Im stuck on part c).

I know that if $e$ is a positive factor of $p-1$ then the equation:
$$X^e \equiv 1 \quad \textrm{mod p} $$ 
has exactly $e$ solutions modulo $p$, the proof of which involves *Fermat's Little Theorem* and *Lagrange's Theorem* so I think it may be relevant but I don't know how to apply it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know about primitive roots?

Comment: One way to proceed is to observe that $f:\Bbb{Z}_p^*\to\Bbb{Z}_p^*, f(x)=x^{(p-1)/d}$, is a homomorphism of groups. You seem to know the size of the kernel of this homomorphism. Are you familiar with results relating the size of the image to the sizes of the domain and the kernel?

Comment: See also : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/871817/congruence-of-nth-degree  and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806684/xn-2mod-13

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each non-zero $x^{(p-1)/d}$ is a root of $x^d\equiv 1\pmod{p}$. So, there are at most $d$ distinct values of $x^{(p-1)/d}$.